# Gnuplot: How to create multiple x labels

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to have multiple x labels in one plot using Gnuplot?

My data file looks like:

```
A dog 10
A cat 20
A fish 14
B dog 15
B cat 44
B fish 5
```

Desired output, something like:

```
dog | cat | fish | dog | cat | fish
       A         |        B
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Third column are y values

Comment: You could do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63889185/7295599

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for, but if your data were formatted like this:

*infile*

```
Label     dog   cat   fish
A         10    20    14
B         15    44     5
```

You can get pretty close:

```gnuplot
set yrange [0:50]
set style data histogram
plot for [col=2:4] 'infile' using col:xtic(1) title columnheader fs solid .3
```

[image: Result of plot command]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your datafile format is under your control, you might want you change your datafile to look like this:

```
dog 10 15
cat 20 44
fish 14 5
```

The following script should give you what you want:

```
set style histogram cluster gap 2
set boxwidth 1.5
unset xtics
set ytics
set auto y
plot newhistogram "A", 'data.dat' using 2:xtic(1) \
newhistogram "B", '' u 3:xtic(1)
```